# I don't understand why error is generated in drools rule

Tags: drools

I am beginner for drools.
I have two type similar code.

First code is working find. But second code is not working.

I don't understand why this code is different.

Please check this issue.

**Rule file - working find**

```
 rule "VoLTE Validate Rule"
 dialect "mvel"
 when
      $uBody : VoLTEBody()
 then
       ArrayList ltErrorCd = new ArrayList();
       ErrorCD_Intl uErrCdOut = new ErrorCD_Intl("0001", "10", 1, "IMSI");
       ltErrorCd.add(uErrCdOut);

       String[] ltErrCd = new String[5];
       ErrorCD_Intl eachErrorCd = ltErrorCd.get(0);
       ltErrCd[0] = new String(eachErrorCd.sErrCd);
 end
```

**Rule file - not working**

```
  rule "VoLTE Validate Rule"
  dialect "mvel"
  when
       $uBody : VoLTEBody()
  then
       ArrayList ltErrorCd = new ArrayList();
       ErrorCD_Intl uErrCdOut = new ErrorCD_Intl("0001", "10", 1, "IMSI");
       ltErrorCd.add(uErrCdOut);

       String[] ltErrCd = new String[5];
       for (int i=0; i<ltErrorCd.size(); i++) {
            ErrorCd_Intl eachErrorCd = ltErrorCd.get(i);
            ltErrCd[i] = new String(eachErrorCd.sErrCd);
       }
   end
```

**Error**

```
   Caused by: org.mvel2.PropertyAccessException: [Error: unable to resolve method: org.drools.core.base.DefaultKnowledgeHelper.eachErrorCd() [arglength=0]]
   [Near : {... rCd[i] = new String(eachErrorCd.sErrCd); ....}]
                                    ^
```

**ErrorCD_Intl Class**

```
 public class ErrorCD_Intl {
        public String sErrCd;
        public String sErrLevelDivCd;
        public int    iErrPriority;
        public String sOldErrCd;

 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a shortcoming of the MVEL language. It simplifies [property navigation](http://mvel.documentnode.com/#bean-properties) by allowing you to write `eachErrorCd.sErrCd` but it expects the class to actually have a getter methods for the field (`getSErrCd()`).

> In situations where the field in the object is public, MVEL will still prefer to access the property via its getter method.

The getter method is obviously missing in your class therefore the expression fails. The error message doesn't help in identifying the cause, I admit.

You have two options to fix the issue:

1. Add the getter method. Its name should probably be `getSErrCd()`.
2. Switch to `java` dialect. In this case, you'll have to add generic type arguments to the `ArrayList`:

   ```
   ArrayList<ErrorCD_Intl> ltErrorCd = new ArrayList<>();
   ```

P.S. I don't understand why the error doesn't occur if you do the same thing outside a for-loop.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I will try to modify my source code.

Comment: I think it actually is a bug in MVEL. "Prefer" means it will use the getter if there is one but it shouldn't fail if it's not there. At least that's what the behavior without for-loop suggests. I'll file an issue.